# duplicate local variable in a static method

Tags: java

in my head I'm initializing a variable named grade and using if else statement to change the variable. but I am getting a duplicate local variable error. I am returning double so I am initializing to 0.0. Am I understanding "scope" wrong here?

```
 public static double finalGrade(double assignment, double midterm, double finalExam) {
            double grade=0.0;

            double midWorth = divide(midterm,20);
            double finalWorth = divide(finalExam,45);
            if(finalWorth < midWorth) {
                double grade = divide((assignment + finalExam),80); 
            }
            else  {
                double grade = divide((assignment + midterm + finalExam), 100);
            }
            return grade;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify the data type `double` only once when you declare the variable. No need when you update the value.

---

There code be like,

```
public static double finalGrade(double assignment, double midterm, double finalExam) {
    double grade=0.0; // declaring

    double midWorth = divide(midterm,20);
    double finalWorth = divide(finalExam,45);

    if(finalWorth < midWorth) {
        grade = divide((assignment + finalExam),80); // updating value
    } else  {
        grade = divide((assignment + midterm + finalExam), 100); // updating value
    }

    return grade;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about the scope of variables

In

```
if(finalWorth < midWorth) {
    double grade = divide((assignment + finalExam),80); 
}
else  {
    double grade = divide((assignment + midterm + finalExam), 100);
}
```

The scope of the `grade` variables in the `if-else` are limited to the `if-else` - not visible outside of the curly braces

so do

```
if(finalWorth < midWorth) {
    grade = divide((assignment + finalExam),80); 
}
else  {
    grade = divide((assignment + midterm + finalExam), 100);
}
```